# How to connect to wifi with local access only?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, local

I need to connect to my modem through local only, while the other computers continue to have both local and internet connectivity.

Is this possible?

My OS is Windows 7 64bit

Comment: On some routers, you can limit access to Internet for selected host names. Consult the manual of your wifi router to see if it supports such functions.

Comment: Can you name the function or is it possible to do it from OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows 7 Home Premium:

```
Start - Control Panel - Firewall - "Advanced Settings"
This will open up "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" Window
Click on "Outbound Rules" and "New Rule"
Rule Type: Custom
Program: All Programs
Protocol and Ports: Any
Scope: Any IP Address (both local and remote)
Action: Block the connection
Profile: Domain and Private (Untick Public)
Name: Make a name for this rule

Click on Finish
```

And now you have an outbound Rule that blocks All Application from accessing any IP on any Port on Domain and Private (Home or Work or Private Networks)

Comment: You are saying i get local onky connection with that?

Comment: I'm saying you can use that to block internet traffic. You will need to create an Inbound rule as well if you don't want things coming in, but since you just seem to not want to get to the internet, Outbound should be sufficient. Just exclude any IPs on your network that you still want to access.

Comment: you mean like the ip that i use to connect to modem like 192.168.1.1

Comment: i mean if i allow 192.168.1.1 i can have my local connection or allowing that ip will open internet access?

Comment: Allowing 192.168.1.1 will allow access to whatever in your network has that address which, I suspect, is your router. This will allow access to the router, but nothing else

Comment: so for each pc i got to add there ip in the same way right